# Ceate CSV show error for page unresponsive

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, csv

I am creating CSV from fetching data from MySQL data base. there are around 18000 rows and 8 columns but it show me Page `unresponsive error`  and show me `kill page` or `wait`:

[image]

I've used following code.

```
function report_print()
{           
    date   = time();
    $myFile = "report_$date.csv";
    $this->load->library('parser');
    $stringData = $this->input->post('data');
    $fileArray  = $this->getdata($stringData);
    $this->generateconvert_to_csv($fileArray, $myFile, ',');
    die;
}
```

I have also tried to create CSV with jQuery with following code but it shows me error for " Network fail".

```
jQuery.fn.tableToCSV = function() {

    var clean_text = function(text){
        text = text.replace(/"/g, '""');
        return '"'+text+'"';
    };

    $(this).each(function(){
            var table = $(this);
            var caption = $(this).find('caption').text();
            var title = [];
            var rows = [];

            $(this).find('tr').each(function(){
                var data = [];
                $(this).find('th').each(function(){
                    var text = clean_text($(this).text());
                    title.push(text);
                    });
                $(this).find('td').each(function(){
                    var text = clean_text($(this).text());
                    data.push(text);
                    });
                data = data.join(",");
                rows.push(data);
                });
            title = title.join(",");
            rows = rows.join("\n");

            var csv = title + rows;
            var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
            var download_link = document.createElement('a');
            download_link.href = uri;
            var ts = new Date().getTime();
            if(caption==""){
                download_link.download = ts+".csv";
            } else {
                download_link.download = caption+"-"+ts+".csv";
            }
            document.body.appendChild(download_link);
            download_link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(download_link);
    });

};
```

Anyone's Help will be appreciated for how to create a CSV with this much record without any issue ?

Comment: Instead of loading full data, load it partially and load only portion that you can view on page.

Comment: Its works fine with that way but not when we load full data in csv as it create issue. I need help for that.

Comment: Or somehow way faster: Generate a JSON or XML and display that using javascript (benchmarked this once: Somehow this is way faster then HTML rendering even when you generate the same elements with your JS)

Comment: Why do you want to load everything? You only need to load whatever the user can see, not more :)